# Mongoose find latest entry

Tags: node.js, socket.io, mongoose

I have an entry which looks like the below:

```
{
  "__v": 10,
  "_id": "50f8050ed714645500000002",
  "sid": "DI7gZ0sprJ",
  "lines": [
    {
      "text": "Well that's what some people say anyway",
      "_id": "50f80526d714645500000003",
      "user": "Player456"
    },
    {
      "text": "They're people just like the rest of us",
      "_id": "50f805925543712caf000005",
      "user": "Player123"
    },
  ],
  "title": "Test",
  "maxlines": 0
}
```

and have a socket.io script like below:

```
socket.on('sendchat', function (data) {
    Story.findOne({ sid: socket.room }, function(err, story){
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
        else if(story == null) {
            console.log(err);
        }
        else {
            io.sockets.in(socket.room).emit('updatechat', socket.username, data);
            story.maxlines = story.maxlines - 1;

            if (story.maxlines == 0) {
                // End Game Script - Redirect to view page
                io.sockets.in(socket.room).emit('gameover', slugs(story.title), socket.room);
            }
            //Save Story to DB
            story.lines.push({
                user: socket.username,
                text: data
            });
            story.save(function(err, story){
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                }
                else {
                    console.log("Story Updated");
                }
            });
        };
    });
});
```

Is there a way I can check to see if socket.username equals the user on the newest line that has been entered?

For example above Player123 is the last one to enter a line, so if Player123 tries again it just emits an error, but if Player456 enters a line, then Player123 is able to again

I'm trying to create a simple turn based game, which checks to make sure a person cannot enter a line when it's not their turn

Comment: There's not even a question mark in your question.

Comment: @thejh looks like i saved submitted it before i completed the question, updated now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly check the last entry in the `lines` array in the `story` object.  As in:

```
if (story.lines.length &&
    story.lines[story.lines.length-1].user === socket.username) {
    // error, same user is trying to enter another line
}
```

Comment: Thanks!, didn't realise that i could do it that way, i was thinking i had to sort and limit the story object. But your solution worked perfectly!

Comment: is there a way to check if its the first entry? because at the minute if your the first person entering the line it errors because there is no previous one to check, i was thinking something like this? `story.lines[story.lines.length-1].user == socket.username && story.maxlines < 10` but that does not seem to work

Comment: @Tam2 Sure, only do the check when `lines` isn't empty.  Updated answer.